# Formulate logistic regression in R

Tags: r

I am having difficulty in R finding a way to obtain the formula used for a logistic regression. Ideally, I would like to get the value of each coefficient in the formula that R came up with from the regression analysis. At the very least, I want the value for the 'steepness' of the curve.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.

Comment: The coefficient will tell you the steepness of the curve, but on a logit (log(p/(1-p))) scale, which may not be what you're after. Steepness of the "non logit" curve is the derivative of the function at a particular point.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "logistic regression in r" the first page has an example that shows how to get coefficients.

If your object is:

```
LogRegression = glm(...)
```

You can get the coefficients with

```
summary(LogRegression)
```

Or more directly with

```
coef(LogRegression)
```

Comment: and probably `coef(LogRegression)[2]` for the (logit-scale) slope ...